# How do you input and output text with Pyscript?

Tags: python, html, input, output, pyscript

I’m learning py-script where you can use `<py-script></py-script>` in an HTML5 file to write Python Code. As a python coder, I would like to try web development while still using python, so it would be helpful if we could output and input information using py-script.

For example, could someone explain how to get this function to work:

```
<html>
     <head>
          <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pyscript.net/alpha/pyscript.css" />
          <script defer src="https://pyscript.net/alpha/pyscript.js"></script>
     </head>
     <body>
          <div>Type an sample input here</div>
          <input id = “test_input”></input>
          <-- How would you get this button to display the text you typed into the input into the div with the id, “test”--!>
          <button id = “submit-button” onClick = “py-script-function”>
          <div id = “test”></div>
          <div 
<py-script>

<py-script>
     </body>
</html
```

I would appreciate it and I hope this will also help the other py-script users.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I checked [source code](https://github.com/pyscript/pyscript) on GitHub and found folder [examples](https://github.com/pyscript/pyscript/tree/main/pyscriptjs/examples).

Using files [todo.html](https://github.com/pyscript/pyscript/blob/main/pyscriptjs/examples/todo.html) and [todo.py](https://github.com/pyscript/pyscript/blob/main/pyscriptjs/examples/todo.py) I created this `index.html`
(which I tested using local server `python -m http.server`)

Some elements I figured out because I have some experience with JavaScript and CSS - so it could be good to learn JavaScript and CSS to work with HTML elements.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
  <!--<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pyscript.net/alpha/pyscript.css" />-->
  <script defer src="https://pyscript.net/alpha/pyscript.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div>Type an sample input here</div>
  <input type="text" id="test-input"/>
  <button id="submit-button" type="submit" pys-onClick="my_function">OK</button>
  <div id="test-output"></div>

<py-script>
from js import console

def my_function(*args, **kwargs):

    #print('args:', args)
    #print('kwargs:', kwargs)

    console.log(f'args: {args}')
    console.log(f'kwargs: {kwargs}')
    
    text = Element('test-input').element.value

    #print('text:', text)
    console.log(f'text: {text}')

    Element('test-output').element.innerText = text
</py-script>

  </body>
</html>
```

---

Here screenshot with JavaScript console in `DevTool` in Firefox.

It needed longer time to load all modules
(from `Create pyodine runtime` to `Collecting nodes...`)

Next you can see outputs from `console.log()`.
You may also use `print()` but it shows text with extra error `writing to undefined ...`.

[image]

Comment: Can someone provide a version that works in the lateast Pyscript release?

Comment: @Maksiks it seems code is still correct for latest Pyscript - so it doesn't need changes. You can even see `Element('test-output').element.innerText = "Hello World!"` in documentation [How to write content to the page](https://docs.pyscript.net/latest/tutorials/writing-to-page.html). It seems they also added shorter version `display("Hello World!", 'test-output')`. I think version `pyscript.write('test-output', "Hello World")` may also work.

Comment: @Maksiks BTW: my code may need changes in links to JavaScript code - `latest` instead of `alpha`. It may need also `py-click` instead of `pys-onClick`. But I didn't check it yet, so I can't confirm it. Maybe later I will change code in answer when I check it.

Comment: it's been a few days and I finished it after realizing I need to use py-click instead of pys-onClick

Answer (score 2):

An alternative to way to display the output would be to replace the

```
Element('test-output').element.innerText = text
```

by

```
pyscript.write('test-output', text)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also `prompt()` the user for `input()`...

```py
import contextlib

with contextlib.suppress(ImportError):
    from pyscript import window
    input = window.prompt

text = input('Please type an sample input here')
```