# How to create an input box using py-script?

Tags: html, pyscripter, pyscript

I want to create a box for a website where you can put integers or a float in html using py-script.

I tried using tkinter but it is removed from the Python standard library in the Pyodide distribution due to browser limitations.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you input and output text with Pyscript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72093397/how-do-you-input-and-output-text-with-pyscript)

Comment: Use the HTML DOM elements such as `<input>`. Everything in PyScript is just a layer above the web browser DOM.

Answer (score 0):

```py
import contextlib

with contextlib.suppress(ImportError):
    from pyscript import window
    input = window.prompt

ints_or_floats = input("Please enter some ints or floats.")
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/349538) would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please edit your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made.