# PyScript not adding random module

Tags: pyscript

I wrote a simple guessing numbers python game and I want it to be available on a web browser. I created an html file inside the same folder when i pasted the code to my html inside the  tags nothing showed up. I also tried adding  tags in the head to show path. I tried it all but nothing seems to work. Pleas help !!

Here is some screenshots of what I tried. [1 METHOD I TRIED](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UOzjU.jpg)
[2ND METHODI TRIED](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DkAOK.jpg)
[3RD METHOD](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GIn4E.jpg)[4TH METHOD](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FNnJN.jpg)

I tried all suggestion on youtube and on the web nothing works.

Comment: Based on what did you try things? Videos get outdated fast. Use current documentation for pyscript. Start with something that works and then line by line add what you want to do. Then determine when it breaks. That is where your problem is. Then research that problem in relation to pyscript. (Hint: You'll probably end up [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76001015/how-do-you-use-an-input-in-pyscript), [where John Hanley's comment here references](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74294901/8508004) and [here](https://github.com/pyscript/pyscript/issues/239#issuecomment-1122366501).)